# Cypress upload file - cypress-file-upload error on huge file

Tags: cypress

Hello I am trying to upload a 10MB file using Cypress last version and this package:
[cypress-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload)

this is the line that doesn't work:

```
  cy.get('[data-cy]="...."').attachFile(fileToAttach);
```

By the way, If the file is small works fine, but if the file is more than 5MB doesn't work.

I don't have any Cypress error, but the file has not been uploaded, seems the form reject the file.
i tried already to put cy.wait() but still doesn't work.

any idea?

thanks in advance
Andrea.

Comment: Can you manually upload the 10MB file?

Comment: yes i can, and with a small file it works fine